# HTTP Thread Pooling and JNDI Datasource Connection pools

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jboss, wildfly

I'm looking for some best practice and advice on how to configure the thread pool in jboss/wildfly for processing http requests when compared with the size of a connection pool of a JNDI data source.

Although there are other web apps running on the server, a new web services application uses Spring security for authentication, which calls my database via a JNDI retrieved JDBC datasource. If an exception is thrown whilst authenticating, Spring security interprets that as an authentication failure and returns a 401, which makes sense.

We have throttling implemented as a custom Spring security filter, which works on a user by user, endpoint by endpoint basis, and requires the authentication look up before it is applied.

When hammer the service with jmeter to test the throttling, I start to see 401 responses coming back, because there are no more JDBC connections available. Essentially jboss/wildfly has enough HTTP threads to handle the requests, but not enough JDBC connections to match.

I'm reluctant to increase the datasource connection pool to match the HTTP thread pool as that seems stupid. I was wondering if there is any best practice around this issue. For the moment I'm thinking that adding something extra to the Spring security exception handling to check the exception that's thrown and return a 503 if it's out of JDBC connections instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your http threads will wait for db connection pool to return a connection object so check wait time it may be very small .

Comment: Indeed, but if I'm hammering with 1000s of requests the wait time will increase.

Comment: I have added a wait time, so at least an exception is thrown if the time is exceeded. All the requests are actually going through ok, albeit slowly, but that's to be expected.